# Create Memory layer in pyQGIS with projected coordinates

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, pyqgis, epsg, memory-layer

I am trying to make a memory layer in QGIS using python and then generate a grid base on calculations in meters. When I run the script, a banner comes and says the CRS is not defined. Then when I look at the derived information I see that the area of the Geometry and its position is wrong.

```
vector_layer = QgsVectorLayer('Polygon?crs:epsg=3879&field=ID:integer(3)&field=value:double','test',"memory")
poly = QgsGeometry.fromPolygonXY([[
    QgsPointXY(34.18639744, 95.15668787),
    QgsPointXY(12.0161471 , 82.35668787),
    QgsPointXY(24.8161471 , 60.18643753),
    QgsPointXY(46.98639744, 72.98643753)])
f = QgsFeature(vector_layer.fields())
f.setGeometry(poly)
vector_layer.dataProvider().addFeatures([f])
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vector_layer)
```

This code will generate a square, but the location is wrong. 
I tried to define CRS afterward in the code:

```
crs = vector_layer.crs()
crs.createFromId(3879)
vector_layer.setCrs(crs)
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(vector_layer)
```

But it did not work either.
Can you please tell where I am making mistake?

Comment: your  `QgsVectorLayeris`is  not correct, the correct crs definition is `crs=EPSG:3879`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Fran Raga said, you probably have a typo in your layer definition.

The reference system is set using `?crs=epsg:3879` and not `?crs:epsg=3879`.

Check the [QGIS Python API | Class: QgsVectorLayer](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.16/core/QgsVectorLayer.html#qgis.core.QgsVectorLayer) for more details:

> crs=definition Defines the coordinate reference system to use for the
> layer. definition is any string accepted by
> [`QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.createFromString()`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.16/core/QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.html#qgis.core.QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.createFromString)

Change the syntax and try again, it should solve your problem.